# Suppress cookie(s) in Java HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: android, cookies, httpurlconnection

I have an android app that connects to a server. The app appends a cookie to each request. However, I need to suppress this cookie for a request to a specific URI.

Some more details:

- Can't add an empty cookie for this URI - even if only the empty one is sent, the request must be without a cookie.
- Use okHTTP3 for this request. It's ugly but it'll work.
- Looked at HttpUrlConnection, CookieStore and CookieManager - could not find any API to disable sending of cookie for a connection
- I prefer not to disable cookies in general but just suppress this one